# Calling directive function of multiple instance in forEach loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created one directive and one method written inside it.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px; margin-bottom:5px; border-
bottom:dashed 1px silver;"
     ng-repeat="companyInfo in companies">
    <at-grosspay  savepayrolldata="CallToSavePayrollData"
                  companyinfoid="companyInfo.QuerystringID">
    </at-grosspay>
</div>
```

The multiple instances are created on page. 
Now, the controller side I want to call the each directive method from forEach Loop.

at-grosspay directive has a method and that I want to call.

```
angular.forEach($scope.companies, function (companyInfo, key)
{
   <Directive>.DirectiveMethod();
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I recommend you to use a `service`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION IS :**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 collapse in" style="padding:0px;">
        <at-grosspay savepayrolldata="companyInfo.CallToSaveData"
                             companyinfoid="companyInfo.QuerystringID">
        </at-grosspay>
</div>
```

**INITIALIZATION**

```
$scope.companies = response.Response;
angular.forEach($scope.companies, function (companyInfo, key)
{
     companyInfo.CallToSaveData={};
});
```

**USE**

```
$scope.saveData = function()
{
    angular.forEach($scope.companies, function (companyInfo, key)
    {
        companyInfo.CallToSaveData.fnSavedata();
    });
}
```